# graphviz dot flow chart table-labels place and sometimes truncated

Tags: graphviz, dot

I've created a quite big flow diagram. Some of the edge-labels (rendered as tables) have these problems:

- the text in some table cells ends up outside the table cell
- the table sometimes crosses the edge
- when the flow diagram is rendered as a PNG image (which is my desired output), 
  then some parts of these tables are outside the image area

The idea of this graph is to have a horizontal timeline, with "column nodes" happening at the same time (or close together in the timeline). So to enforce this "time flow" I ended up using `rankdir="LR";` along with `{rank=same; my_first_node; my_second_node; }`.

**How do I make those "table labels" a bit better rendered? Like not crossing the edges, having the text completely inside their table cell, seeing the full graph when exporting to PNG?**

I generate the PNG output image with this command: `dot -Tpng foo.dot -o foo.png`, see below the "table label" issues:

```
digraph my_flow {
  // global graph conf
  rankdir="LR"; // orziontal
  nodesep=0.9;

  // shared conf
  edge [ fontname="Courier New", fontsize=20];
  node [ fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=26, style="rounded,filled", nojustify=true];

  // many different node "classes"
  node[shape=doublecircle, color=navajowhite]
    my_first_node; my_second_node;
  node[shape=rect, color=aquamarine2]
    first_std_horiz_node; second_std_horiz_node;

  // custom configuration for each node
  first_std_horiz_node[label="First \l std \l horizontal \l node"]
  second_std_horiz_node[label="Second \l std \l horizontal \l node"]
  my_first_node[label="My \l first \l node"]
  my_second_node[label="My \l second \l node"]

  // sets of nodes in the same "column"
  {rank=same; my_first_node; my_second_node; }

  first_std_horiz_node -> second_std_horiz_node
  second_std_horiz_node -> my_first_node
  my_first_node -> my_second_node [label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
                             <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 1</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action 1 very very very very long description</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 2</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action X</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action Y</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 3</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action A</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action B</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action C</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 4</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action Q</TD></TR>
                             <TR><TD>action W</TD></TR>
                           </TABLE>>];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put your table in a node rather than an edge label, things look better; and using  the HTML Tag `<BR/>`, you can break lines in the table. Editing your code accordingly, I come up with

```
digraph my_flow {
  // global graph conf
  rankdir="LR"; // horizontal
  nodesep=0.9;

  // shared conf
  node [ fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=26, style="rounded,filled", nojustify=true];

  // node instead of edge label
  my_table[ shape=none, margin=0, fontname="Courier New", fontsize=20, label=<
          <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 1</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action 1<BR/>very very very very<BR/>long description</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 2</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action X</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action Y</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 3</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action A</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action B</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action C</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 4</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action Q</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action W</TD></TR>
         </TABLE>> ]

  // many different node "classes"
  node[shape=doublecircle, color=navajowhite]
    my_first_node; my_second_node;
  node[shape=rect, color=aquamarine2]
    first_std_horiz_node; second_std_horiz_node;

  // custom configuration for each node
  first_std_horiz_node[label="First \l std \l horizontal \l node"]
  second_std_horiz_node[label="Second \l std \l horizontal \l node"]
  my_first_node[label="My \l first \l node"]
  my_second_node[label="My \l second \l node"]

  // sets of nodes in the same "column"
  {rank=same; my_first_node; my_table; my_second_node; }

  first_std_horiz_node -> second_std_horiz_node -> my_first_node;
  my_first_node -> my_table[ dir = none ];
  my_table -> my_second_node;
}
```

which yields

[image]

EDIT

After the revisions in the table code, it is also possible to use the table as a label; for easier reference here the full code again:

```
digraph my_flow {
  // global graph conf
  rankdir="LR"; // horizontal
  nodesep=0.9;

  // shared conf
  node [ fontname=Helvetica, fontsize=26, style="rounded,filled", nojustify=true];

  // node instead of edge label


  // many different node "classes"
  node[shape=doublecircle, color=navajowhite]
    my_first_node; my_second_node;
  node[shape=rect, color=aquamarine2]
    first_std_horiz_node; second_std_horiz_node;

  // custom configuration for each node
  first_std_horiz_node[label="First \l std \l horizontal \l node"]
  second_std_horiz_node[label="Second \l std \l horizontal \l node"]
  my_first_node[label="My \l first \l node"]
  my_second_node[label="My \l second \l node"]

  // sets of nodes in the same "column"
  {rank=same; my_first_node; my_second_node; }

  first_std_horiz_node -> second_std_horiz_node -> my_first_node;
  my_first_node -> my_second_node[ fontname="Courier New", fontsize=20, label=<
          <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 1</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action 1<BR/>very very very very<BR/>long description</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 2</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action X</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action Y</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 3</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action A</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action B</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action C</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="gray">action type 4</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action Q</TD></TR>
           <TR><TD BGCOLOR="white">action W</TD></TR>
         </TABLE>> ];
}
```

which yields

[image]

In the given context I find the node solution preferable / cleaner, as it makes it clearer where the info in the table belongs to. But if there is more to it, the edge way will also work.

Comment: It is a pity that `<COL ...>` is not supported by Graphviz.

Comment: @vaettchen I was hoping to separate "actions" from "states/entities" using edges and nodes. Most of the times those tables are tiny and fit well near edges (with curves). This way I think it's clear what's the purpose of these tables when looking at the graph, because they don't mix with nodes. Anyway, yes this node trick seems to avoid most of the issue regarding the rendering of a big table. Thanks!

Comment: @TPPZ, see my edit - edge works as well if you control the width of the table.